# If x, y and z are rational and strictly positive and if $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{z}$, show that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is rational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

This is a question from "Pathfinder to Mathematical Olympiads", I know that we need to prove that $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is a perfect square of a rational number. I did prove it but I'm wondering if there's a better solution than mine. And there is no solution given in the textbook.
I'm not able to add a pic of my solution so I'll briefly explain it.

$\ z = \frac{xy}{x+y}$, so I found the value of $\ x^2+y^2+z^2$ as a fraction in terms of x and y.

The denominator turned out to be $\ (x+y)^2$ which is a perfect square. So I factored the numerator and showed that it was a perfect square. Hence the whole fraction is a perfect square.
I hope you understood my solution.

P.S. I'm only 13 years old, so please don't put too advanced solutions.

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. Please edit and add your solution, so we can look for a different solution.

Comment: Ok, fine I'll do it.

Comment: Prove that all solutions $(x,y,z)$ to $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{z}$ s.t. $x,y,z>0$ are rationals take the form $x=au(u+v)$, $y=av(u+v)$, and $z=auv$ for some rational numbers $a,u,v>0$ (you can take $u$ and $v$ to be coprime positive integers).  Use this to show that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=a(u^2+uv+v^2)$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool, More direct, substituting $z=\frac{xy}{x+y}$, the square root equals $\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x+y}$

Comment: @Atticus, That's what I did too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace $z$ by $-z$, we get $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} = 0$ and do not change $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, then we can calculate that $xy + yz + zx = 0$, so $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2(xy + yz + zx) = (x + y + z)^2$, and $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = x + y + z$ is rational.

Comment: But how can you just replace z with -z?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{z}$ can be easily transformed into $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{-z} = 0$, and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = x^2 + y^2 + (-z)^2$

Comment: But then xy-yz-xz=0 when z is positive

Comment: @SujalMotagi If you don’t want to change signs, expand $(x+y-z)^2$ and use that $xy-yz-zx=0$ as you noted.